# MySQL Query log

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can find out how many select, update, insert and rest of the queries have been executed by MySQL server ? Can it be in last 1 day or week ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way! You can set the server to write logs about client connects/disconnects and every statement which was executed to a log file. Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. is it recommended to keep it on during production environment always ?

Comment: Sure, if you want to log the queries in some way, it has to. If you need it to inspect a particular error, you can turn it on just for the duration you need it to. Anyways, it's a good position for you to have an insight what queries are executed on your machine for troubleshooting.

Comment: i didnt know much about these concept as I am new to this site. but I am getting answers pretty immediately. let me accept answers from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

Start General Query Log, it allows storing log info into table.

Then write a SELECT query to read data from `mysql`.`general_log` table, add WHERE condition to filter result by date. Then analyze (parse) data from the `argument` field, it contains executed queries.

Comment: thanks for the answer. is it recommended to keep it on during production environment always ?

Comment: Agree with stb about using query log. Turn on it just for the debugging purposes.